# Ajax not posting data to controller

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I am posting data through ajax to a action, but the problem I am not able to get the data posted through ajax in my controller action. While debugging, the call gets transferred to action but I dont get anything in data not even 'null'.

here is my ajax call,

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:' @Url.Action("PostAmount", "Deal")',
            data: { country: 2, amount: 4.02 },
            datatype:JSON,

            success: function (data) {
                alert("hiiii"+data);
            }
        });
```

and my action,

```
 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult PostAmount(int country,double amount)
        {
            AllocationViewModel mod = new AllocationViewModel();
            return Json(mod);
        }
```

Comment: see in console that on your given url request is going or not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var dataToPost = "{ country:'" + 2 + "', amount:" + 4.02 + "}";

$.ajax({
    url: @Url.Action("PostAmount", "Deal")',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: dataToPost,
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/jsonrequest; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        alert("hi"+ data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:' @Url.Action("PostAmount", "Deal")',
        data: { "country": "2", "amount": "4.02" },
        datatype:JSON,

        success: function (data) {
            alert("hiiii"+data);
        }
    });
```

or the best solution is to save the values in an object and use the jquery function "stringify" and then send the values over. that should work.

Comment: still not getting the data in controller :(

Answer (score 0):

try putting json in quotes

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:'@Url.Action("PostAmount", "Deal")',
    data: { country: "2", amount: "4.02" },
    dataType:"json",
    traditional:true,
    success: function (data) {
        alert("hiiii"+data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `JSON.stringify(yourObject)` on your object to make it a JSON object. This makes it easier to create objects in javascript and pass then into the data parameter of your post request.
Also use a string for the datatype parameter (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), as suggested in the answers above.

```
var dataToPost = { country: 2, amount: 4.02 };

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:' @Url.Action("PostAmount", "Deal")',
    data: JSON.stringify(dataToPost),
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        alert("hiiii"+data);
    }
});
```

The other way around is `JSON.parse(yourJsonObject)`. This way you can parse a JSON string into a Javascript object.